# drupal 7 view module question

Tags: view, drupal-7

i have created view , in short it display last 5 news title and image
and put them in front page
but specifically i want to show only the image of the first node and the rest only title of them , so what the proper procedure .
is there api  a documentation for this module so i can go through its functions and properties and print what i need.

here is a summary query for the created view but i think it won't be useful for what i need:

```
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.language AS node_language, 'node' AS field_data_field_img_node_entity_type FROM  {node} node LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_index} taxonomy_index ON node.nid = taxonomy_index.nid LEFT JOIN {taxonomy_term_data} taxonomy_term_data ON taxonomy_index.tid = taxonomy_term_data.tid WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN ('news')) AND (taxonomy_term_data.name LIKE 'Lates News' ESCAPE '\\') )) LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done completely through the Views interface.  Change your display to show the titles of 4 news nodes with an offset of 1.  Then, add an attachment display that outputs a single node and set it to display the title and image.  Then, attach that display before the other display.